# Finding files ISO-8859-1 encoded?

Tags: bash, encoding, utf-8

I have a bunch of files with a mixtures of encodings mainly ISO-8859-1 and UTF-8.

I would like to make all files UTF-8, but when trying to batch encode this files using
iconv some problems arise. (Files cuts by half, etc.)

I supposse the reason is that iconv requires to know the 'from' encoding, so if the command looks like this

```
iconv -f ISO-8859-1 -t UTF-8 in.php -o out.php
```

but 'in.php' if already UTF-8 encoded, that causes problems (correct me if I'm wrong)

Is there a way, that I can list all the files whose encoding is not UTF-8?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't find files that are definitely ISO-8859-1, but you can find files that are valid UTF-8 (which unlike most multibyte encodings give you a reasonable assurance that they are in fact UTF-8). [moreutils](http://kitenet.net/~joey/code/moreutils/) has a tool `isutf8` which can do this for you. Or you can write your own, it would be fairly simple.

Answer (score 3):

It's often hard to tell just by reading a text file whether it's in UTF-8 encoding or not. You could scan the file for certain [indicator bytes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Description) which can never occur in UTF-8, and if you find them, you know the file is in ISO-8859-1. If you find a byte with its high-order bit set, where the bytes both immediately before and immediately after it don't have their high-order bit set, you know it's ISO encoded (because bytes >127 always occur in sequences in UTF-8). Beyond that, it's basically guesswork - you'll have to look at the sequences of bytes with that high bit set and see whether it would make sense for them to occur in ISO-8859-1 or not.

The `file` program will make an attempt to guess the encoding of a text file it's processing, you could try that.

Answer (score 3):

with find it's quite simple

```
find . -print0 | xargs -0 file | grep 8859
```

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way, that I can list all the files whose encoding is not UTF-8?

Perhaps not so easily in bash alone, but it's a trivial task from eg. Python:

```
import os.path

for child in os.path.listdir(TARGETDIR):
    child= os.path.join(TARGETDIR, child)
    if os.path.isfile(child):
        content= open(child, 'rb').read()

        try:
            unicode(content, 'utf-8')
        except UnicodeDecodeError:
            open(child, 'wb').write(unicode(content, 'iso-8859-1'))
```

This assumes that any file that *can* be interpreted as a valid UTF-8 sequence *is* one (and so can be left alone), whilst anything that isn't must be ISO-8859-1.

This is a reasonable assumption if those two are the only possible encodings, because valid UTF-8 sequences (of at least two top-bit-set characters in a particular order) are relatively rare in real Latin text, where we tend only to use the odd single accented characters here and there.

Answer (score 0):

What kind of content?  XML?  Then yes, if properly tagged at the top.  Generic text files?  I don't know of any a-priori way to know what encoding is used, although it might be possible, sometimes, with clever code.  "Tagged" UTF-8 text files, by which I mean UTF-8 text files with a [Byte-Order mark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte-order_mark)?  (For UTF-8, the three byte sequence "ï»¿")  Probably.  The Byte Order Mark characters will not *commonly* appear as the first three characters in a ISO-8859-1 encoded file. (Which [bobince](https://stackoverflow.com/users/18936/bobince) pointed out in a comment to this post, so I'm correcting my post.)

For your purposes, tools exist that can probably solve most of your question.  Logan Capaldo pointed out one in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588843/finding-files-iso-8859-1-encoded/588861#588861).

But after all, if it were always possible to figure out, unambiguously, what character encoding was used in a file, then the `iconv` utility wouldn't need you to provide the "from" encoding.  :)

Comment: UTF-8 files should not, ‘properly’, have a BOM (although in practice they often do. And a UTF-8-encoded BOM can perfectly well exist at the beginning of an ISO-8859-1 file (it would mean “ï»¿”)... it's just very unlikely, of course.